# Get count of top-level deleted documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am looking to get an accurate count of deleted Elasticsearch documents excluding the nested documents at Lucene level. I am aware of the following APIs to get document and deleted document counts but none of them return the information I need.

- `GET myindex/_count API` - Returns the top-level Elasticsearch documents.
- `GET _cat/indices/myindex API` - Returns `docs.count` & `deleted.docs` that are taken directly from Lucene and include nested documents.
- `GET _cat/count/myindex API` - Returns the top-level documents same as the 1st option.

For example:
Suppose an index with `10` documents that are internally stored as `100` Lucene documents and I delete 5 documents, I want to get 5 instead of the count of deleted Lucene docs.

**Is there a way to get the top-level deleted documents?**

Comment: I'm curious about the use case here. Since segments are being merged all the time in the background the number of deleted count can change.

Comment: Sorry I am new to elasticsearch and wondering in what use case it would be like `Suppose an index with 10 documents that are internally stored as 100 Lucene documents ` ?

Comment: @java-dev when you have a [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) in your mapping, all elements of the nested array are stored as separate hidden documents.

Comment: @Val I work on a platform product that is built on top of Elasticsearch and we use the deleted count as an indication of the number of top-level documents that are deleted recently. The deleted.docs from the _cat API doesn't help here. As for segment merging, our policies are tuned to run merging operations only when required and not constantly.